# User status field, how to map to an enum

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a User model, and I want to have a user_status attribute.

I want this attribute to be stored as an integer in the database.

I was thinking of then creating a enum, and then mapping that enum to the integer value so I could do things like:

```
if user.status == MyEnum::RequiresApproval
..
..
```

Using active_record, at the model level, is there something I can do with the enum?

What is normally done in this kind of situation?

Answer (score 2):

Enums are not very Rails like.  State Machines are.

Check out the 'transitions' gem ([link](https://github.com/qoobaa/transitions)) (which was almost part of Rails Core)

And then you can do the following ...

```
 #GemFile
 gem "transitions", :require => ["transitions", "active_record/transitions"]


 #And in your Model, do something like the following:
  include ActiveRecord::Transitions

  field :state, type: String
  scope :active, where(state: 'active')

  state_machine do
    state :active
    state :inactive

    event :inactivate do
      transitions :from => :active, :to => :inactive
    end

    event :activate do
      transitions :from => :inactive, :to => :active
    end
  end
```

It was a transition for me too not to use enums and type tables -- but I haven't missed them

Comment: sure does -- that code i used i took from a Mongoid model  (mongoid is the best!)